# Oh, Say Can You See?

Tags: history, word-order

In the Star Spangled Banner, the opening line/question is "Oh, say can you see..."

Is that grammatically correct?  Why isn't it "Oh, say you can see...?"

Comment: Let's not forget the jr high version:  *Jose, can you see?*

Answer (score 7):

It's in the correct order.

From NOAD:

> **say** ... *exclam*. informal
>   used to express surprise or to draw attention to a remark or question: *say, did you notice any blood?*

So think of that line being punctuated as:

> O, say, does that star-spangled banner yet wave?

It's the equivalent of "Tell me, does that ... etc."

Answer (score 4):

Statement "you can see" is reversed for a question "can you see".

Comment: +1 for making explicit that it's a question, which was only hinted at in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

The first four lines of the song are a single very long question. The core of the question is: "Can you see what we hailed?"

This question is then made much longer by adding a lot of additional phrases. Here I've marked the core question in bold, and the additional phrases with parentheses:

> (Oh say,) **can you see**, (by the dawn's early light,) **what** (so proudly) **we hailed**, (at the twilight's last gleaming), (whose broad stripes and bright stars, through the perilous fight o'er the ramparts we watched, were so gallantly streaming)**?**

Answer (score 1):

It's grammatically correct. It's like saying:

> Wow! Say, can you do that again?

In the same way, in the anthem, "O!" is an exclamation, and "say" is being used as an [interjection:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/say)

> (used to express surprise, get attention, etc.)

Answer (score -4):

The Star Spangled Banner was written in 1814. It seems very likely that there were more blind people then as optical science wasn't quite yet up to par.

[Linguistic relativity,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity) states that linguistic category and usage influence thoughts and decisions. Perhaps this construct was once valid but is no longer valid because we have fewer blind people today and thus don't need such a wide way to query what they can't see and whether they're blind.

Think about all the words that mean "snow" that we'll lose once all the ice caps melt away.

Comment: Not even close.

Comment: The song is ultimately asking "can you see what we hailed (whose stars and stripes were gleaming)"; you're saying that this is literally asking if the addressee is a sighted person? That really doesn't make any sense to me.